# Spring Boot app doesn't read configuration from Consul if started before Consul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul

When I start Consul, then the app, and then create some configuration, the app would read it and apply at runtime.

However if the app is started before Consul it wouldn't be able to read the configuration and its changes.

According to the official documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/reference/html/ (Section **5. Consul Retry**) it could be fixed.

I applied the recommendations there by adding the following dependencies to the project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and using the following settings in bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-service
  cloud:
    consul:
      config:
        enabled: true
        fail-fast: false
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      retry:
        max-attempts: 100
        enabled: true
        initial-interval: 1000
        max-interval: 2000
```

However it didn't help. What can go wrong?

Using:

```
spring-cloud-starter-consul-config:jar:3.0.1
spring-boot.version=2.4.3
spring-cloud-starter-consul:jar:3.0.1
boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html (section **7.4 Config Client Retry**) I also had to set `spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true` which wasn't intuitive to me but it solved the issue.